# 12 V input to multiple 5 V outputs?

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, converter

I have that project, where I have as an input voltage 12 V (lead acid battery) and would like to have 4 output of 5 V 1 A that would be switched on and off with a mosfet.
I'm thinking which way you would recommend me to proceed.

- Option 1 : Use a single voltage converter 12 V to 5 V with 4 A( for the 4 outputs) and then have the 4 mosfets connected to the 5 V line of the output.
- Option 2 : Use 4 voltage converters 12 V to 5 V with 1 A for each outputs connected to the battery and connect each output to a mosfet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on other requirements such as cost, space, noise/isolation between rails etc. Usually you either have a strong reason to use separate supplies or you do a single supply which you split.

Comment: As puffafish said, the best way to do it would depend on some other things too. Do you have any constraints? Are you working to a PCB with a set shape/size, or do you have any cost constraints? Are the locations of the 4 separate 5V devices near each other? Would using a single supply mean you will have frustrations with running power traces all over the PCB? Could the devices possibly draw more than 1A each, and potentially affect a single supply?

Comment: Currently I have no constraints. It's possible that devices could draw more than 1A and was also thinking of a way to limit the current drawn but that is a different question. So yes, as of now no constraints, besides having a safe and efficient design. Maybe I should have asked which advantages one option has over the other one?

Comment: Other things to think about:

Having one main supply would improve the load sharing (1 or 2 device above 1A nominal, others below still add up to 4A), costs may be lower 4A regulators generally aren't 4x price of 1A regulators.  Fewer parts to fail, but failure means entire system is shut down 4 x 1A has redundancy.

Comment: Option 3: Use 12V to 5V switching DC/DC regulators with an enable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is the simplest and probably least expensive, since you only have a single supply plus 4 MOSFETS.

Option 2 could be done without MOSFETs by using a regulators that have an enable input.

Note that because of the large voltage differential and high current, a switching supply is the best choice.  That means that option 2 has 4 inductors, which could be a significant difference in size and cost.

A third option would be to use a single high current switching supply to convert 12V to ~5.5V, and then use low cost linear LDOs with enable inputs to convert the 5.5V to 5V.  This has the added benefit of reducing the switching noise in the 5V output, since the final stage is a linear regulator.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will either go with option 2 or your 3rd option. Actually I have not thought about that approach. I plan to use the mosfet and buck converter sips since I don't want to bother with designing the circuit of the switching regulator. I couldn't find a sip with an enable pin so the mosfet will have to be used, unless I manage to find one.